# Как организовать роутинг?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

В проекте есть небольшое количество постов, у каждого из которых есть своя категория. Эти категории входят в навигационную панель, ссылки которой имеют следующий вид:

```
      "categoryList" : {
          "All" : "/category/all",
          "News" : "/category/news",
          "Story" : "/category/story"
        }
```

Роутинг прописан вот такой :

```
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/category/:category" component={PostsList}/>
              <Route path="/post/:id" component={PostCard}/>
              <Route path="/" component={NewPost}/>
            </Switch>
```

Фильтрация постов по категориям происходит на сервере, т.е. при переходе на определенную категорию мне нужно запрашивать результат оттуда. Изначально я в самом компоненте PostsList запрашиваю посты с сервера в componentDidMount(), используя категорию, полученную из this.props.match.params.category, здесь всё работает как надо. При переходе по другим категориям мне нужно обновлять список постов, каким образом это лучше сделать?

Были попытки запроса постов в componentDidUpdate(), но выходила ошибка
*Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял из вопроса, вы храните загруженные данные в локальном стейте компонента. Загружая данные в методе `componentDidUpdate`, вы снова вызываете `setState`, который снова вызывает `componentDidUpdate`. Поэтому, как одно из решений, можно добавить в `componentDidUpdate` условие того, что обновилась только категория перед загрузкой данных.

Но вместо использования `componentDidMount` я бы рекомендовал использовать [useEffect](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). Это упростит код. Нужно лишь помнить, что компонент должен быть функциональным.

```js
const PostsList = props => {
  const { category } = props.match.params;
  const [list, setState] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    fetch(`/some/api?category=${category}`)
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(data=> setState(data));
  }, [category])

  return ...
}
```